# Expo router with Expo layout cause inifity loop

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

1. SDK Version: ^48.0.7
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): IOS & ANDROID

I got a "reset password" button in my "signIn" component, when user press the button it will route user to the component "resetPwd.tsx".
But it will cause infinity render loop beetween "resetPwd.tsx" and "_layout.tsx"
Here is the log
[image]
[image]

Here is the "signIn" component content of how to handle the event when user press the "reset password" button.
[image]

And here is my project strucutre

[image]

The conetnt of resetPwd.tsx
[image]

The content of _layout.tsx under the "sign_in" folder.
[image]
[image]

I dont know what should I do, Thanks you all.